I changed the embedded object, but the document was not saved
I am changing the Embedded Object from the Google Docs Api, but the document itself is not saved.
Why?
$doc = $this->service->documents->get($this->iddoc);
  $inlineObjects = $doc->getInlineObjects();
  foreach ($inlineObjects as $key => $value) {
           $imgProp = $value->getInlineObjectProperties();
           $emb= $imgProp->getEmbeddedObject();

           $emb->setDescription('koukou__'.$key);
           $emb->setTitle('koukou__'.$key);

           $size = $emb->getSize();
           $m = $size->getHeight();
           $m->setMagnitude(140);
           $size->setHeight($m);
           $emb->setSize($size);
           $imgProp->setEmbeddedObject($emb);
           $value->setInlineObjectProperties($imgProp);
        }
   $doc->setInlineObjects($inlineObjects);```


From your showing script, I guess that your showing script is not your whole script. About but the document itself is not saved, in your script, it seems that the object is retrieved from Google Document by $doc = $this->service->documents->get($this->iddoc);. Where can I see the script for requesting the request body for "Method: documents.batchUpdate"?

This is the whole script. I'm trying to put a Description of the image, but I can't do anything. I did not find which Batch Update to do

Thank you for replying. When I checked "Method: documents.batchUpdate", unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, there are no methods for changing the title and description of the inline image on Google Document in Google Docs API. Ref But, fortunately, the Document service (DocumentApp) of Google Apps Script can achieve your goal. So, how about using Google Apps Script? If this was not your expected direction, I apologize.
